# Java args passar arquivo como parâmetro

Tags: java, argumento

Estou fazendo um trabalho de grafos onde tenho que fazer uma biblioteca e depois de gerado o jar na execução preciso informar dois parâmetros que são arquivos txt, no primeiro estarão os dados de entrada no segundo a saida.A minha duvida é como faco para passar dois txts como parâmetro do args ?

Comment: Passar o caminho dos arquivos como parâmetro e instanciar como [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) na aplicação?

Comment: Fiz exatamente isso ao invés de tentar passar os arquivos eu passo os caminhos deles e funcionou certinho.

Comment: Vou colocar como resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de tentar passar os arquivos por parâmetro, passe o caminho dos arquivos e instancie com a classe [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) na aplicação.

```
public static void main(string[] args){
    for(String arq : args){
        File file = new File(arq);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public  void passarArquivos( String ... paths ) { 

        File arquivo ;

        for (String caminho : paths) {

            arquivo = new File( caminho );

            System.out.println(" Nome :"+ arquivo.getName() );

        }

 }


 public static void main(String[] args) {

        SuaClass suaClass = new SuaClass();

        suaClass.passarArquivo("C:\\arquivo1.txt" , "C:\\arquivo2.txt" );
 }
```